# Grok pattern to retrieve Processor id from Nifi logs

Tags: apache-nifi, grok, logparser

**Can anyone help me getting right Grok pattern to retrieve only id value from below sample logs(only message part) from nifi**

1. o.a.n.c.s.StandardControllerServiceNode StandardControllerServiceNode[service=DBCPConnectionPool[id=5609ac16-0174-1000-eeee-ffffd19aae44]
2. o.a.n.c.s.StandardControllerServiceNode Failed to invoke @OnEnabled method of DBCPConnectionPool[id=5609ac16-0174-1000-hhhh-ffffd19aae44]
3. o.a.n.c.s.StandardControllerServiceNode Failed to invoke @OnEnabled method of DBCPConnectionPool[id=5609ac16-0174-1000-gggg-ffffd19aae44]*

I have tried using the below pattern but it is retrieving the whole message but unable to get id value separately

- *%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp} %{LOGLEVEL:severity} [%{DATA:thread}] %{DATA:class} %{GREEDYDATA:message}*

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to extract the id then you can use the following pattern.

```
\[id=%{DATA:id}\]
```

This will match on the [id= and then grab everything before the next ].

You could make this more robust by defining a custom pattern that more accurately matched the ID pattern, rather than using DATA.

I use the following resources for GROK patterns

1. https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-patterns-core/blob/master/patterns/grok-patterns
2. https://grokconstructor.appspot.com/do/match

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like below that captures the UUID from the log.

```
filter {
   grok{
     match =>  { "message" => "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}%{SPACE}%{LOGLEVEL:severity}%{SPACE}\[%{DATA:thread}\]%{SPACE}%{DATA:class}%{SPACE}%{GREEDYDATA}\[id=%{UUID:id}\]%{GREEDYDATA}"} 
   }
}
```

It should give an output like below

```
{
        "thread" => "Curator-Framework-0",
            "id" => "5609ac16-0174-1000-eeee-ffffd19aae44",
    "@timestamp" => 2020-10-06T11:24:24.703Z,
          "path" => "/usr/share/logstash/stack/data/data.log",
     "timestamp" => "2016-08-04 13:26:35,475",
      "severity" => "DEBUG",
      "@version" => "1",
          "host" => "356136d6f0b4",
       "message" => "2016-08-04 13:26:35,475 DEBUG [Curator-Framework-0] o.a.n.c.s.StandardControllerServiceNode StandardControllerServiceNode[service=DBCPConnectionPool[id=5609ac16-0174-1000-eeee-ffffd19aae44]"
}
```

given that the sample log entry is

```
2016-08-04 13:26:35,475 DEBUG [Curator-Framework-0] o.a.n.c.s.StandardControllerServiceNode StandardControllerServiceNode[service=DBCPConnectionPool[id=5609ac16-0174-1000-eeee-ffffd19aae44]
```